# Custom onFailure Call in Unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm currently in the process of writing some unit tests I want to constantly run every few minutes. If any of them ever fail, I want to grab the errors that are raised and do some custom processing on them (sending out alerts, in my case). Is there a standard way of doing this? I've been looking at unittest.TestResult, but haven't found any good example usage. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wound up running the test and returning the `TestResult` object. I then look at the `failures` attribute of that object, and run post processing on each test in the suite that failed. This works well enough for me, and let's me custom design my post-process.

For any extra meta data per test that I need, I subclass `unittest.TestResult` and add to the `addFailure` method anything extra that I need.

Answer (score 3):

We use a continious integration server jenkins for such task. It has cron like scheduling and can send an email when build becomes unstable (a test fails). There is an extention to python's unittest module to produce junit style xml report supported by jenkins.